# В классе TagHelper получить текущий url c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url

Представим пустой класс для создания TagHelper :

```
public class HyperLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
        }
    }
```

И я хочу чтобы tag-хелпер в зависимости от url делал определенную задачу, но как получать url я не могу найти.На HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri VS ругается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var url = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
    }
}
```